# Разница между вызовом исключения и if...else

Tags: python

**Не кидайте камнями если ответ очевиден,или вопрос сформулирован неправильно,я в программировании зеленее травы!**
Изучаю python по книге a byte of python,дошел до главы вызов исключения,где
говорится что можно создать подкласс(назовем его myError) надкласса Expection,и
по мере необходимости вызывать его,к примеру: `class myError(Exception): pass`,
а затем вызвать его через if..else: `if a == 'abc': raise myError`,и затем обработать эту ошибку `except myError: print('Error!')`.
Так почему же нельзя сделать так: `if a == 'abc':print('Error!')` вместо примера сверху,зачем использовать классы,когда той же цели можно достигнуть(мне кажется что можно,возможно это не так) с 
помощью if..else?

Comment: Потому что ошибка - это очевидно и удобно. Прикладывается Traceback и наглядное описание (которое Вы и указываете). К тому же используется `stderr` поток, что отделяет ошибку от стандартного `stdout` вывода.

Comment: Если действительно того же самого можно добиться с помощью if-else, то их и стоит использовать. Но в некоторых ситуациях исключения таки удобнее. Например, исключение пробрасываются вверх по всему стеку вызовов. Соответственно, это полезно, когда ситуация возникает внутри функции, а отловить и обработать её нужно в коде, который вызывал функцию, которая вызывала функцию, которая вызывала функцию, ...., которая вызывала функцию с отлавливаемой ситуацией. Без исключений вам бы пришлось самостоятельно прокидывать информацию об ошибке через все эти функции.

Comment: На самом деле, во время обучения на отдельных скриптах или простеньких учебных проектах польза исключений действительно не очень очевидна. Я всю мощь исключений познал только когда поработал на реальном проекте под сто тысяч строк кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основной плюс от использования исключений - это удобство отладки.
К любому исключению прикладывается полный Traceback, какой бы глубокой не была вложенность.

Также стоит отметить, что ошибки записываются в `stderr`. Система отличает их от обычного вывода и может принимать какие-либо действия.

*Например:*

- IDE на основе `stderr` может указать на ошибку в коде
- `Supervisor` может записывать ошибки в отдельный файл

*и т. д.*

Comment: Исключение — дорого. В варианте, когда можно обработать ошибку (не фатальную), лучше обрабатывать ошибку.